# How to reduce this ruby code?

Tags: ruby

This is the code:

```
def explaination_exists
explaination_exists_flag = false
if self.explanation1.length > 5
  explaination_exists_flag = true 
end
if self.explanation2.length > 5
  explaination_exists_flag = true 
end
if self.explanation3.length > 5
  explaination_exists_flag = true 
end
if self.explanation4.length > 5
  explaination_exists_flag = true 
end

unless explaination_exists_flag
  errors.add(:base, 'Atleast one explanation should be there.')
end
end
```

I want to reduce the code to a single line code, since there is no change except for  explaination[number].

I have tried this:

```
 def explaination_exists
 explaination_exists_flag = false
 (1..4).each do |i| 
  if self."explanation#{i}".to_sym.length > 5 
  explaination_exists_flag = true
  break 
  end
end
unless explaination_exists_flag
  errors.add(:base, 'Atleast one explanation should be there.')
end
end
```

I know this is silly but can you suggest me some alteration that might work.

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you have a long list of variable names which look like var `i`..`j`. You are using the wrong data structures to store that information. Please refactor the code which gets `explaination`1,2,3.... Perhaps there is a better way to store those variables. May be in an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def explaination_exists
  return if (1..4).any?{|i| send("explaination#{i}").length > 5}
  errors.add(:base, "Atleast one explanation should be there.")
end
```

Comment: Actually i wanted to check if ANY of the explanation.length > 5. Anyways it worked with some changes, thanks!

Comment: I'd personally remove the `return` and change the `if` to an `unless`.

Comment: @Phrogz If it fits in one line so that I can use the postfix syntax, then I would do that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my quick stab at it:

```
def explanation_exists
    return true if [explanation1, explanation2, explanation3, explanation4].map(&:length).any? { |length| length > 5}
    errors.add(:base, 'Atleast one explanation should be there.')
end
```

Comment: even nicer than mine :)

Comment: Best way in fact, I always forget any? method

Comment: It's giving an error that method 'length' is not defined. Thanks anyways!

Comment: yeah, that's because I corrected the spelling of explanation. :)

Comment: `length` is not defined because `map(:length)` return an array of length. So you should correct your condidition block by `{ |ex| ex > 5 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
def explanation_exists
  [:explanation1, :explanation2, :explanation3, :explanation4].inject(false) do |result, method|
    result || (self.send(:method).length > 5)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def explaination_exists
  return true if %w{ explanation1 explanation2 explanation3 }.map do |exp|
                self.send("#{exp}").length > 5
              end.detect { |e| e }

  errors.add(:base, 'Atleast one explanation should be there.')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate this a bit, something like:

```
def explanations
  [explanation1, explanation2, explanation3, expanation4]
end

def explanation_exists
  errors.add(:base, :explanation) unless explanations.any? { |e| e.length > 5 }
end
```

And put the error message in your locale under `activerecord.errors.models.<your-model-name>.attributes.base.explanation` (IIRC).